# How to convert java time to date in oracle table?

Tags: java, oracle, date, time

I have table with column write_date type NUMBER.
I found that in that column saved Date.getTime();
Does exist Oracle function that can return me date like DDMMYYYY ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
cast(to_date('01-jan-1970','dd-mon-yyyy') + your_long/86400000 as timestamp ) ts
```

Comment: 21/03/5351 11:09:30.000000
21/03/5351 11:14:48.000000
18/04/5351 21:29:27.000000
18/04/5351 21:31:00.000000
26/04/5351 11:26:37.000000
26/04/5351 11:27:10.000000
26/04/5351 11:27:10.000000
27/04/5351 02:32:18.000000

Answer (score 1):

Cast your number as a date using [to_date](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96540/sql_elements4a.htm) with the 'ddmmyyyy' format. Further information can be found at the link, which is to the Oracle documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
to_char(to_date(1970,'yyyy') + java_time/86400000, 'ddmmyyyy')
```